# g_main_context_invoke And to improve the performance

Tags: glib

There are X and Y.

X is a daemon.
Y is a so lib.

X call the function A in Y lib.

It takes long time to finish A function.

So X has big problem.

I want to improve it to make another thread... or etc..
(It's impossible to reduce time of A.)

A is

```
bool A (callback)
{
    ...   /* some dbus init */
    ...   /* some other job init */
    ...
    g_main_context_invoke(NULL, _functionA, callback);
    return true;
}
```

So I change it like below.

I make A1 function. And change X call the A1 function instead of A.

```
int A1(callback)
{
    g_idle_add(A, callback);
    return true;
}
```

Result is A doesn't finish.
I don't know why.. I assume because of "g_main_context_invoke(NULL, _functionA, callback);"

Is there any one to improve this problem ??

Comment: I think you need to specify a lot more context.  Operating system, compiler version, language (it looks like C++, but can't be sure) and libraries (where does `g_main_context_invoke` come from?) would make it a lot easier for someone to try to answer the question

Comment: It use gcc compiler. And I use glib library.

Comment: More context, what threads are they running in (main thread, spawned thread, thread of a threadpool, in what context do they get called, etc..)